# Connecting to remote Glassfish hosted EJB

Tags: networking, glassfish, ejb, rmi, jndi

The application i'm currently working on start to enter in a pre-release phase.

In this phase, the server-side application components are to be deployed on Amazon VMs while the client-side application remains on the user machine.

This applications connects to server using JNDI and RMI to call remote EJB methods. This works well on `localhost` and local network.

But, when trying to connect to Amazon host, the application hangs up on context.lookup method. that's to say a JNDI context can be obtained from this remote server, but no lookup can be performed on that context.

What can I do to obtain good diagnostic on the failure ?

Are there logs that can be generated for the RMI handshake/whatever ?

Is there any way to see on server side if query really drive its way through the internet to the server ?

Also notice I've already enabled public IP usage on my Glassfish server ([using recommended Oracle procedure](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2418/beakv.html#ghbpc)).

**EDIT** According to a fast TCP capture on server, it seems that server receives the client context query with in-lan client address, which it of course isn't aware of :

query is

```
[3/27/2012 11:05:22 AM:169]
GIOP.......(................NameService....._is_a...................
NEO................ª.......(IDL:omg.org/SendingContext/CodeBase:1.0.
...........n........172.27.63.145.Üº....¯«Ë........e................
........... ................... ... ...........&...............(IDL:
omg.org/CosNaming/NamingContext:1.0.
```

reply is

```
[3/27/2012 11:05:22 AM:171]
GIOP.......2............NEO................0.......(IDL:omg.org/Send
ingContext/CodeBase:1.0............ô........46.137.114.67.'5....¯
«Ë........d........................... ................... .........
.....&...........!...|...............$....f............10.241.42.208
.'6.@........g..............g........default...................g....
...........+IDL:omg.org/CosNaming/NamingContextExt:1.0..............
.......10.241.42.208.'5...M¯«Ë.... ...d...  S1AS-ORB............Root
POA....TNameService............................... .................
.. ...  ...........&......
```

(as read using SmartSniff ASCII output).

The IP in query (`172.27.63.145`) is my IP in my company LAN. From what I understand of communication over itnernet, it should be my company LAN public IP, no ? How can I make Glassfish client udnerstand it should use that IP ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Diagnostic has been clearly obtained : the client, which connects from a LAN to the server, sends its own internal network private address to server, which server can't forward any answer to. As a consequence, server doesn't answer, hence the hangup.